# Where or what to edit to resize column in a table?

Tags: php, html-table, oscommerce

I wonder where and what I have to edit to make the first column in my oscommerce template (the one with the delete checkbox) smaller.
I have spend 2 evenings try finding the data which van alter this column, at this point, everything failed.

This is a link to the template I have, any help would be great.

[The link to the template is here](http://osc2.template-help.com:8081/14116/shopping_cart.php?osCsid=8853f10a0483769548f6aca72b1f26e0)

this is the complete code for the shopping_cart.php (excuse me for posting the whole code, but I don't see an other way to show what happends in php.

Can anyone tell me which file to edit so I can alter the width of the first column as seen in the link?

```
<?php
/*
  $Id: shopping_cart.php,v 1.73 2003/06/09 23:03:56 hpdl Exp $

  osCommerce, Open Source E-Commerce Solutions
  http://www.oscommerce.com

  Copyright (c) 2003 osCommerce

  Released under the GNU General Public License
*/

  require("includes/application_top.php");

  require(DIR_WS_LANGUAGES . $language . '/' . FILENAME_SHOPPING_CART);

  $breadcrumb->add(NAVBAR_TITLE, tep_href_link(FILENAME_SHOPPING_CART));
?>
<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html <?php echo HTML_PARAMS; ?>>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?php echo CHARSET; ?>">
<title><?php echo TITLE; ?></title>
<base href="<?php echo (($request_type == 'SSL') ? HTTPS_SERVER : HTTP_SERVER) . DIR_WS_CATALOG; ?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" topmargin="0" bottommargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0">
<!-- header //-->
<?php require(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'header.php'); ?>
<!-- header_eof //-->

<!-- body //-->
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
<!-- left_navigation //-->
<?php require(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'column_left.php'); ?>
<!-- left_navigation_eof //-->
    </td>
<!-- body_text //-->
    <td width="100%" valign="top"><?php echo tep_draw_form('cart_quantity', tep_href_link(FILENAME_SHOPPING_CART, 'action=update_product')); ?><table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>

<?php tep_draw_heading_top();?>

<? new contentBoxHeading_ProdNew($info_box_contents);?>


<?php
  if ($cart->count_contents() > 0) {
?>
<?php
    $info_box_contents = array();
    $info_box_contents[0][] = array('align' => 'left',
                                    'params' => 'class="shop_cart_txt" style="width:2%;"',
                                    'text' => '<b>'.TABLE_HEADING_REMOVE.'</b>');

    $info_box_contents[0][] = array('params' => 'class="shop_cart_txt" style="3%"',
                                    'text' => '<b>'.TABLE_HEADING_PRODUCTS.'</b>');

    $info_box_contents[0][] = array('align' => 'center',
                                    'params' => 'class="shop_cart_txt" style="width:10%;"',
                                    'params' => 'class="shop_cart_txt" style="width:10%;"',
                                    'text' => '<b>'.TABLE_HEADING_QUANTITY.'</b>');

    $info_box_contents[0][] = array('align' => 'center',
                                    'params' => 'class="shop_cart_txt " style="width:37%;"',
                                    'text' => '<b>'.TABLE_HEADING_TOTAL.'</b>');

    $any_out_of_stock = 0;
    $products = $cart->get_products();
    for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($products); $i<$n; $i++) {
// Push all attributes information in an array
      if (isset($products[$i]['attributes']) && is_array($products[$i]['attributes'])) {
        while (list($option, $value) = each($products[$i]['attributes'])) {
          echo tep_draw_hidden_field('id[' . $products[$i]['id'] . '][' . $option . ']', $value);
          $attributes = tep_db_query("select popt.products_options_name, poval.products_options_values_name, pa.options_values_price, pa.price_prefix
                                      from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_OPTIONS . " popt, " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_OPTIONS_VALUES . " poval, " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_ATTRIBUTES . " pa
                                      where pa.products_id = '" . (int)$products[$i]['id'] . "'
                                       and pa.options_id = '" . (int)$option . "'
                                       and pa.options_id = popt.products_options_id
                                       and pa.options_values_id = '" . (int)$value . "'
                                       and pa.options_values_id = poval.products_options_values_id
                                       and popt.language_id = '" . (int)$languages_id . "'
                                       and poval.language_id = '" . (int)$languages_id . "'");
          $attributes_values = tep_db_fetch_array($attributes);

          $products[$i][$option]['products_options_name'] = $attributes_values['products_options_name'];
          $products[$i][$option]['options_values_id'] = $value;
          $products[$i][$option]['products_options_values_name'] = $attributes_values['products_options_values_name'];
          $products[$i][$option]['options_values_price'] = $attributes_values['options_values_price'];
          $products[$i][$option]['price_prefix'] = $attributes_values['price_prefix'];
        }
      }
    }

    for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($products); $i<$n; $i++) {
      if (($i/2) == floor($i/2)) {
        $info_box_contents[] = array('params' => 'class=""');
      } else {
        $info_box_contents[] = array('params' => 'class=""');
      }

      $cur_row = sizeof($info_box_contents) - 1;

      $info_box_contents[$cur_row][] = array('align' => 'center',
                                             'params' => 'class="" valign="top"',
                                             'text' => '<br style="line-height:1px;"><br style="line-height:25px;">' .tep_draw_checkbox_field('cart_delete[]', $products[$i]['id']));

      $products_name = '
                                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style=" width:249px;">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>'.tep_draw_separator('spacer.gif', '5', '1').'</td>
                                                        <td><a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_PRODUCT_INFO, 'products_id=' . $products[$i]['id']) . '">' . tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $products[$i]['image'], $products[$i]['name'], SMALL_IMAGE_WIDTH, SMALL_IMAGE_HEIGHT) . '</a><br>';



      if (STOCK_CHECK == 'true') {
        $stock_check = tep_check_stock($products[$i]['id'], $products[$i]['quantity']);
        if (tep_not_null($stock_check)) {
          $any_out_of_stock = 1;

          $products_name .= $stock_check;
        }
      }

      if (isset($products[$i]['attributes']) && is_array($products[$i]['attributes'])) {
        reset($products[$i]['attributes']);
        while (list($option, $value) = each($products[$i]['attributes'])) {
          $products_name .= '<br><small><i> - ' . $products[$i][$option]['products_options_name'] . ' ' . $products[$i][$option]['products_options_values_name'] . '</i></small>';
        }
      } 
        $products_name .= ' </td>
                                                        <td>'.tep_draw_separator('spacer.gif', '5', '1').'</td>
                                                        <td width="1" height="103" class="bg22">'.tep_draw_separator('spacer.gif', '1', '1').'</td>
                                                        <td width="12">'.tep_draw_separator('spacer.gif', '12', '1').'</td>
                                                        <td width="100%">
                                                            <br style="line-height:29px">
                                                    <a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_PRODUCT_INFO, 'products_id=' . $products[$i]['id']) . '">' . substr($products[$i]['name'],0,MAX_DESCR_NAME_SHOPPCART) . '</a></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                            ';








      $info_box_contents[$cur_row][] = array('params' => 'class=""',
                                             'text' => '<br style="line-height:1px">'.$products_name);

      $info_box_contents[$cur_row][] = array('align' => 'center',
                                             'params' => ' class="form_1" valign="top"',
                                             'text' => '<br style="line-height:1px;"><br style="line-height:25px">'.tep_draw_input_field('cart_quantity[]', $products[$i]['quantity'], 'size="4"  id="input1"') . tep_draw_hidden_field('products_id[]', $products[$i]['id']));

      $info_box_contents[$cur_row][] = array('align' => 'center',
                                             'params' => 'class="" valign="top"',
                                             'text' => '<br style="line-height:1px;"><br style="line-height:25px"><b>' . $currencies->display_price($products[$i]['final_price'], tep_get_tax_rate($products[$i]['tax_class_id']), $products[$i]['quantity']) . '</b>');
    }

    new productListingBox($info_box_contents);
?>

<?php
    if ($any_out_of_stock == 1) {
      if (STOCK_ALLOW_CHECKOUT == 'true') {
?>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td class="stockWarning" align="center"><br><?php echo OUT_OF_STOCK_CAN_CHECKOUT; ?></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
<?php
      } else {
?>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td class="stockWarning" align="center"><br><?php echo OUT_OF_STOCK_CANT_CHECKOUT; ?></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo tep_draw_separator('pixel_trans.gif', '100%', '1'); ?></td>
      </tr>
  </table>

<?php
      }
    }
?>
                                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"class="product box_product">                                       
                                        <tr>
                                            <td bgcolor="#DDDDDD" width="100%" style=" vertical-align:middle; text-align:right; padding-top:2px;"><b><?php echo SUB_TITLE_SUB_TOTAL; ?></b>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td bgcolor="#DDDDDD" height="26" style=" vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;"><?php echo tep_draw_separator('spacer.gif', '77', '1'); ?><strong><?php echo $currencies->format($cart->show_total()); ?></strong></td>
                                        </tr>                                               
                                    </table>
                                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="485" height="74">
                                                <br style="line-height:15px"><?php echo tep_draw_separator('spacer.gif', '20', '1'); ?><?php echo tep_image_submit('button_update_cart.gif', IMAGE_BUTTON_UPDATE_CART); ?><?php echo tep_draw_separator('spacer.gif', '17', '1'); ?><?php
    $back = sizeof($navigation->path)-2;
    if (isset($navigation->path[$back])) {
 echo '<a href="' . tep_href_link($navigation->path[$back]['page'], tep_array_to_string($navigation->path[$back]['get'], array('action')), $navigation->path[$back]['mode']) . '">' . tep_image_button('button_continue_shopping1.gif', IMAGE_BUTTON_CONTINUE_SHOPPING) . '</a>'; 
    }
?><?php echo tep_draw_separator('spacer.gif', '16', '1'); ?><?php echo '<a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_CHECKOUT_SHIPPING, '', 'SSL') . '">' . tep_image_button('button_checkout.gif', IMAGE_BUTTON_CHECKOUT) . '</a>'; ?><br>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>


<?php
  } else {
?>

    <br style="line-height:1px;"><br style="line-height:5px;">


            <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td align="center" class="main"><br><?php new infoBox_78(array(array('text' => TEXT_CART_EMPTY))); ?><br style="line-height:1px;"><br style="line-height:15px;"></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="10"><?php echo tep_draw_separator('pixel_trans.gif', '10', '1'); ?></td>
                <td align="right" class="main"><?php echo '<a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT) . '">' . tep_image_button('button_continue.gif', IMAGE_BUTTON_CONTINUE) . '</a>'; ?><br><br></td>
                <td width="10"><?php echo tep_draw_separator('pixel_trans.gif', '10', '1'); ?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr><td colspan="3" height="5"></td></tr>
            </table>



<?php
  }
?>
<?php tep_draw_heading_bottom();?>

    </table>



    </form></td>

<!-- body_text_eof //-->
    <td valign="top">
<!-- right_navigation //-->
<?php require(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'column_right.php'); ?>
<!-- right_navigation_eof //-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- body_eof //-->

<!-- footer //-->
<?php require(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'footer.php'); ?>
<!-- footer_eof //-->
<br>
</body>
</html>
<?php require(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'application_bottom.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked the output html. I see that all element that have class="" also have width=50% (include first column). 
This maybe help you figure out st.

```
$info_box_contents[$cur_row][] = array('align' => 'center',
                                             'params' => 'class="" valign="top"',
                                             'text' => '<br style="line-height:1px;"><br style="line-height:25px;">' .tep_draw_checkbox_field('cart_delete[]', $products[$i]['id']));
```

try to to set `class="something"` and add specify `width` for `params` here may work otherwise 
need source of `productListingBox` class to check more!

Comment: ahh great!! I did see the width 50%, but couldn't find the source of it. the file I needed to edit was the boxes.php. Thanks again.